# Using Espresso: Hamcrest toplevel and NoClassDefFound

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror, hamcrest, android-espresso

I am trying to add [Espresso](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/Espresso) to test our app.

When I **do not** have the `hamcrest-1.1.jar` in the `build.gradle`, I receive the following error:

```
com.espresso.PracticeTest > testClickOnActionBar[Nexus 10 - 4.3] FAILED 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.hamcrest.Matchers
at com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withId(ViewMatchers.java:274)
:Example:connectedInstrumentTest FAILED
```

When I **do** have the `hamcrest-1.1.jar` in the `build.gradle`, I receive the following error:

```
 UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: class name (org/hamcrest/beans/HasProperty) does not match path (hamcrest-library-1.1/org/hamcrest/beans/HasProperty.class)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:520)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:665)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:634)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$600(Main.java:78)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:572)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:596)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:498)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:264)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)
...while parsing hamcrest-library-1.1/org/hamcrest/beans/HasProperty.class
```

This is the `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
instrumentTestCompile files('libs/dagger-1.1.0.jar', 'libs/dagger-compiler-1.1.0.jar',
        'libs/hamcrest-library-1.1.jar',
        'libs/espresso-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar', 'libs/guava-14.0.1.jar', 'libs/javawriter-2.1.1.jar',
        'libs/javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar','libs/javax.inject-1.jar',
        'libs/jsr305-1.3.9.jar', 'libs/testrunner-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar',
        'libs/testrunner-runtime-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar')
 }
```

I do a `./gradlew clean build` then `./gradlew example:connectedCheck` to run.

Does anyone have a work-around to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19646529/using-android-gradle-dagger-to-run-instrumenttests/19652380#19652380) is likely to serve you better than my original one

Took quite awhile but I finally got it working. I had to do the following:

1. Declare my dependencies like so:

   ```
   dependencies {
     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
     compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.1.0'
     compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.1.0'

     instrumentTestCompile files('libs/espresso-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar','libs/testrunner-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar','libs/testrunner-runtime-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar')
     instrumentTestCompile files('libs/hamcrest-core-1.1.jar', 'libs/hamcrest-library-1.1.jar', 'libs/hamcrest-integration-1.1.jar')
     instrumentTestCompile 'com.google.guava:guava:14.0.1'
   }
   ```
2. Copy the hamcrest jars from [here](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/source/browse/#git/bin/espresso-dependencies)
3. Remove the license files from the jars like this (or else you'll get an error about duplicate LICENSE.txt files)

   ```
   zip -d hamcrest-core-1.1.jar LICENSE.txt
   zip -d hamcrest-library-1.1.jar LICENSE.txt
   ```
4. Run gradle connectedCheck

A few things to note:
- Hamcrest 1.3 didn't work for me, got an error about a matcher was missing
- Crazy how many hoops I had to jump through to get here.
- Good luck getting this to play well with android studio.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used gradle yet but I had similar issues which only went away when I added all of the hamcrest jars to my classpath.

Adding hamcrest-all.jar didn't work for me only the individuals (lib, core and integration).

That said, it did complain about the license.txt inside of the jars.

This was not a problem I had to time to figure out what the "proper" fix was but removing the license files from the jars and it all started working.